# Unable to add column between two columns using Google spreadsheet Api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a Google spreadsheet. On my E column, I want to add recent month with the year (eg: Sept 2017) if not available on E column.Suppose there is (Aug 2017) and now when I add (Sept 2017) it adds but it replaces the existing column that is Aug 2107. My requirement is to keep both: newly added (Sept 2017) and (Aug 2017).
I want recent month on E column and shift existing column on the right that is F column. I'm doing this using C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  try
  {
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
      HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
      ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
    String spreadsheetId = "1lZnvQe6lTGG81hyuQvf7HjH8YpnIadFlNHjFUq_G-5Q";
    String range = "E1";

    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest getRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
    Data.ValueRange response = getRequest.Execute();

    string recentMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM yyyy");
    var recentMonthArrayValue = new List<string[]>();
    recentMonthArrayValue.Add(new string[] { recentMonth });
    if (response.Values[0][0].ToString() != recentMonth)
    {
      DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
      var currentMonthStartDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1).ToShortDateString();

      Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
      batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Requests = new List<Data.Request>();
      Data.Request request = new Data.Request();
      batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.Requests.Add(request);
      request.UpdateCells = new Data.UpdateCellsRequest();

      var gridCoordinate = new Data.GridCoordinate();
      gridCoordinate.ColumnIndex = 5;
      gridCoordinate.SheetId = 0;
      request.UpdateCells.Start = gridCoordinate;
      request.UpdateCells.Fields = "*";
      request.UpdateCells.Rows = new List<Data.RowData>();
      var rowData = new Data.RowData();
      request.UpdateCells.Rows.Add(rowData);
      rowData.Values = new List<Data.CellData>();
      var cellData = new Data.CellData();
      cellData.UserEnteredValue = new Data.ExtendedValue();
      cellData.UserEnteredValue.FormulaValue = "=TEXT(\"" + currentMonthStartDate + "\",\"MMM yyyy\")";
      rowData.Values.Add(cellData);
      SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest batchUpdateRequest = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest, spreadsheetId);
      batchUpdateRequest.Execute();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //throw;
  }
}
public static UserCredential GetCredential()
{
  UserCredential credential;
  using (var stream =new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
      System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
      Scopes,
      "user",
      CancellationToken.None,
      new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    return credential;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [insert an empty row or column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#insert_an_empty_row_or_column) guide in Sheets API:

> The following spreadsheets.batchUpdate request inserts two blank
>   columns at column C. A second request inserts three empty rows at row
>   1. The inheritBefore field, if true, tells the API to give the new columns or rows the same properties as the prior row or column;
>   otherwise the new columns or rows acquire the properties of those that
>   follow them. inheritBefore cannot be true if inserting a row at row 1
>   or a column at column A.
>
> The request protocol is shown below. The Updating Spreadsheets guide
>   shows how to implement a batch update in different languages using the
>   Google API client libraries.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate


{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 2,
          "endIndex": 4
        },
        "inheritBefore": true
      }
    },
    {
      "insertDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 3
        },
        "inheritBefore": false
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: yes I know it, but i am unable to do it with c#.If you know how to do it with c#, tell me.